# Object required error for named worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

```
 Set Nightletter = ActiveWorkbook

 Nightletter.Sheets("XPT SUMMARY").Activate

 Range("A2").Activate
```

for this code also it shows Object Required error on 2nd line.
I changed it to

```
Nightletter.Sheets("XPT SUMMARY").Activate

Activesheet.Range("A2").Activate
```

It also didn't work.

Comment: how many sheets you have in your `ActiveWorkbook`?

Comment: Unless there is no sheet 2, this should work.

Comment: Is your second worksheet hidden? Try `if Destsheet2.Visible <> -1 then Destsheet2.Visible = -1` before your third line.

Comment: I have 3 sheets and its all visible.

Comment: How have you defined `Destsheet2` Also change `ActiveWorkbook` to `ThisWorkbook`. The active workbook may not be the one that you think it is :) Also [INTERESTING READ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)

Comment: Nightletter.Sheets("XPT SUMMARY").Activate


Range("A2").Activate

for this code also it shows Object Required error on 2nd line.
I chaned it to 

Nightletter.Sheets("XPT SUMMARY").Activate


Activesheet.Range("A2").Activate

It also didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

In case the suggestions in the comments above haven't yet solved your issue, please try to do the following.

Open a fresh copy of Excel. Create a new workbook, and save it as "myWorkbook.xlsm" - a workbook with macros enabled. Make sure it has at least two sheets.

Now open the VBA editor, create a new module, and enter the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub actSheet()
  ' simple code to activate Sheet2 in myWorkbook.xlsm
  Dim wb as Workbook
  Dim ws as Worksheet

  Set wb = Application.Workbooks("myWorkbook.xlsm")
  Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")

  If Not ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
  ws.Activate

End Sub
```

This is using what I believe are Best Practices for what you are trying to do (although it's almost never necessary to Activate a worksheet - see the excellent link in Siddharth Rout's comment above). Specifically:

- Start with `Option Explicit` (so you must declare each variable)
- Include a comment to describe your function
- Declare all variables used
- Build up reference to sheet from workbook, and by name: name less likely to change than order
- Make sure that the sheet you want to activate is Visible

Finally - compare to what you are doing with the above; if you really can't tell the difference, and you are still getting the error, come back and tell us.